# Get All names Parent SQL

Tags: php, sql, laravel, parent, hierarchy

I hope you can help me. I Have a SQL table With Categories where have multi parents like this:

```
$table->id();
$table->string('name');
$table->integer('parent_id');

where: 
ID | NAME | PARENT_ID 
1 | Category_0 | Null 
2 | Category_1 | 1
3 | Category_2 | 2 
4 | Category_3 | 2 
5 | Category_4 | 3 
6 |Category_4 | 1
```

I want a query to have the name of all the parent_id that an id contains, like:

> result if where id is 5 (completeName):
>
> > category_0 > category_1 > category_2 > category_4 ...

Right now I'm doing a foreach inside a foreach to get all the names, but the result is quite slow.

```
$categoryName =  DB::table('categories')->select('*')->where(id, $id)->(I dont know how make the rest)->get()
```

I'm using laravel, but if you can't help me in laravel, at least the query would like to know how to do it, would help me a lot

Best regards

Comment: Do you want to search for id 1 and 2 and get the Category_0 and  Category_1?

Comment: I want search for one id and get all parent names too.
like: category_0 > category_1 > category_2 > category_4 if i search for id 5

Comment: For instance, you search id 5 will return Category_4, and after that the parent Id (Id: 3) that will return Category_2, and after that the parent Id (Id: 2) that will return Category_1 and so on..... right?

Comment: Perhaps you need to research recursive SQL. Add tag for database used. SQL is a language used by many dbs, it is not itself a db.

Comment: Yes its that =) At moment i use php with laravel. Im trying use the NodeTrait nut no sucess